# Key observer not stopping from updating the new value?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am adding a HTML string to the webview, I am monitoring the webview height based on the observer value changes like below.

```
contentSizeObservationToken = observe(\.scrollView.contentSize, options: [.initial, .old, .new]) {[weak self] (_, change) in
```

But the new value is kept on going without stopping, **This is happen only for particular HTML Strings**

Here is one sample HTML that occurs this issue .

[html](https://pastecode.xyz/view/32680a1f)

There was no error message is received

```
    private func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have ended up with storing **height** of the web view to back end , So then while displaying I don't want to weight for did finish , I can increase the height immediately after the api call .